# regex check country code after some string and _

Tags: java, regex

I have to check string `license_<Two digit country code>` with regex have country code after _

for example `license_us`  or `license_ca`

Comment: And what have you tried so far ? SO is not a coding service ;) share your tries

Comment: Why regex? Use basic text processing, since the string is always after `_`.

Comment: `string.split("_")[1]`

Answer (score 0):

This code is getting the remaining string after `_`:

```
String key="license_us";
String country = key.substring(key.indexOf("_") + 1);
System.out.println(country);
```

prints

```
us
```

so why do you need regex?